# React Ag-Grid: Issue with Column Selection - Cross Button Not Refreshing on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

In my React Ag-Grid implementation, I've injected a div to serve as a clickable element for clearing the search input within the column selection. While typing with backspace successfully empties the value, clicking on the cross icon does not have the same effect. I find it peculiar that manual typing achieves the desired result, and I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this discrepancy with the cross button behavior.

I've tried implementing various backspace event solutions, but none seem to be working as expected. The onClick event attached to the cross icon triggers, but the search input doesn't refresh.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9xxG.png)

[default column selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yZYa.png)

[search value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBhsR.png)

[removed value by clicking cross icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybFNL.png)